# Add a value into two nested JSON array with Lambda, Stream java

Tags: java, json, lambda, nested

I'm a bit new in Lambda and streams. After a lot of researches, I couldn't find the proper answer to my problem. But if you know any related answer, please give me the link, and I will delete this question. Thanks.

My problem is I try to convert the following code into Lambda. But because I use indexes and validation into a nested loop, I couldn't be able to turn it in just one block code with Lambda (is it possible?). 
Also, I would be grateful if anyone has a suggestion for writing this code in a better way).

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.length(); i++) {
    if (list1.getJSONObject(i).has("owner")) {
        dataObject1 = list1.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("owner");
        if (GeneralUtils.isNameExist(inputNameOrSubject, dataObject1, true)) {
            if (usersList != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < usersList.length(); j++) {
                    if (
                            GeneralUtils.isNameExist(usersList.getJSONObject(j).getString("first_name"), dataObject1, false) ||
                                    GeneralUtils.isNameExist(usersList.getJSONObject(j).getString("last_name"), dataObject1, false)
                    ) {
                        usersExist = true;
                        usersIndex = j;
                    }
                }
                if (usersExist) {
                    if (list1.getJSONObject(i).has("name")) {
                        topicName = list1.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                        topicListJA = usersList.getJSONObject(usersIndex).getJSONArray("topics");
                        topicExist = false;
                        for (int t = 0; t < topicListJA.length(); t++) {
                            if (topicName.toLowerCase().equals(topicListJA.getString(t).toLowerCase())) {
                                topicExist = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!topicExist) {
                            usersList.getJSONObject(usersIndex).getJSONArray("topics").put(topicName);
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    result = dataObject1;
                    result.put("topics", new JSONArray(new String[]{list1.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")}));
                    usersList.put(result);
                }
            } else if (list1.getJSONObject(i).has("name")) {
                result = dataObject1; 
                result.put("topics", new JSONArray(new String[]{list1.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")}));
                usersList = new JSONArray();
                usersList.put(result);
            }

        }

    }
}
return String.valueOf(usersList);
```

**Update:**
The input list is a JSON array with something like this:

```
[{
    owner: { 
          signature: "",
          created: "2019-08-26 02:14:15", 
          nickname: "",
          last_name: "Kennedy", 
          title: null,
          first_name: "Victor", 
          updated: "2019-11-24 20:58:57",
          email: "v.kennedy@gmail.com"
    },
     topics: [ 
          {
               id:"0"
               name: "topic 1"
          },{
               id:"1"
               name: "topic 2"
          },{
               id:"0"
               name: "topic 3"
          },
     ]
},

{    owner: {
          signature: "",
          created: "2014-03-25 23:51:48",
          nickname: "",
          last_name: "Kent", 
          title: "",
          first_name: "Bill", 
          updated: "2019-11-21 21:26:24",
          email: "bill.kent@gmail.com"
     },
     topics: [ 
          {
               id:"0"
               name: "topic 6"
          },{
               id:"1"
               name: "topic 7"
          },{
               id:"0"
               name: "topic 8"
          },
     ]
} ,
{
     owner: {
          signature: "",
          created: "2014-03-25 23:51:48",
          nickname: "",
          last_name: "Novel", 
          title: "",
          first_name: "Tim", 
          updated: "2019-10-21 21:26:24",
          email: "tim.novel@gmail.com"
     }
     ,
      topics: [ 
          {
               id:"0"
               name: "topic 16"
          },{
               id:"1"
               name: "topic 17"
          },{
               id:"0"
               name: "topic 18"
          },
     ]
 },
{    owner: {
          signature: "",
          created: "2014-03-25 23:51:48",
          nickname: "",
          last_name: "Kent", 
          title: "",
          first_name: "Bill", 
          updated: "2019-11-21 21:26:24",
          email: "bill.kent@gmail.com"
     },
     topics: [ 
          {
               id:"0"
               name: "topic 36"
          },{
               id:"1"
               name: "topic 37"
          },{
               id:"0"
               name: "topic 38"
          },
     ]
}  
]
```

And when the API receives the keyword "ken" as a name, I need to send back the first two JSON objects and last one with combined details for topics value (I mean one JSON object for Bill Kent and combined topic: 6,7,8,36,37,38) as a response!

Comment: The *proper* answer is: Don't, lambdas are not good for everything. Besides, I think you really meant *Streams*, but the answer is the same: Don't, lambdas are not good for everything. Both streams and lambdas are tools, and you should use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. I thought maybe some ways either with stream or lambda or the combination to write this code shorter and efficient. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Could you also post your input and expected output JSON strings? Maybe there are another ways which can achieve what you want!

Comment: @LHCHIN I've updated my question. Thanks

Comment: OK, but what did you mean "combined details"? Could you post the transformed JSON object format?

Comment: BTW, all the keys in your JSON string are not wrapped by double quotes, so I think it is invalid.

Comment: @LHCHIN by combined I meant I should have one JSON object with one owner details and all topics from different received objects which had the same owner. Does it make sense? Cheers

Comment: @LHCHIN I've updated the question with the example

Answer (score 2):

I have to mention it first, your JSON string is not valid. Because you all the keys must be wrapped by double quotes and all the JSON nodes belong to the same JSON array must be separated by comma.

Following code snippet shows another way to achieve what you want. First use a `Map` with `first_name` and `last_name` concatenated by `&` as key, then combine `topics` of JSON node whose key is identical. Finally convert the `Map` to a new JSON node. BTW, `Jackson` (one of the most popular JSON libraries) is introduced to demo this.

**Code snippet**

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 ArrayNode root = (ArrayNode) mapper.readTree(jsonStr);
 Map<String, JsonNode> rootMap = new HashMap<>();
 root.forEach(e -> {
     String firstName = e.get("owner").get("first_name").toString().toLowerCase();
     String lastName = e.get("owner").get("last_name").toString().toLowerCase();
     if (firstName.contains("ken") || lastName.contains("ken")) {
         String key = String.format("%s&%s", firstName, lastName);
         if (rootMap.containsKey(key)) {
             e.get("topics").forEach(e1 -> {
                 ((ArrayNode) rootMap.get(key).get("topics")).add(e1);
             });
         } else {
             rootMap.put(key, e);
         }
     }
 });

 ArrayNode rootNew = mapper.createArrayNode();
 rootMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
     rootNew.add(v);
 });
 System.out.println(rootNew.toString());
```

**Console output**

```
[ 
  { 
    "owner":{ 
      "signature":"",
      "created":"2014-03-25 23:51:48",
      "nickname":"",
      "last_name":"Kent",
      "title":"",
      "first_name":"Bill",
      "updated":"2019-11-21 21:26:24",
      "email":"bill.kent@gmail.com"
    },
    "topics":[ 
      { 
        "id":"0",
        "name":"topic 6"
      },
      { 
        "id":"1",
        "name":"topic 7"
      },
      { 
        "id":"0",
        "name":"topic 8"
      },
      { 
        "id":"0",
        "name":"topic 36"
      },
      { 
        "id":"1",
        "name":"topic 37"
      },
      { 
        "id":"0",
        "name":"topic 38"
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "owner":{ 
      "signature":"",
      "created":"2019-08-26 02:14:15",
      "nickname":"",
      "last_name":"Kennedy",
      "title":"null",
      "first_name":"Victor",
      "updated":"2019-11-24 20:58:57",
      "email":"v.kennedy@gmail.com"
    },
    "topics":[ 
      { 
        "id":"0",
        "name":"topic 1"
      },
      { 
        "id":"1",
        "name":"topic 2"
      },
      { 
        "id":"0",
        "name":"topic 3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here you are! You can get the same result by using `org.json` as below:

```
JSONArray root = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
Map<String, JSONObject> rootMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = root.getJSONObject(i);
    String firstName = obj.getJSONObject("owner").getString("first_name").toLowerCase();
    String lastName = obj.getJSONObject("owner").getString("last_name").toLowerCase();
    if (firstName.contains("ken") || lastName.contains("ken")) {
        String key = String.format("%s&%s", firstName, lastName);
        if (rootMap.containsKey(key)) {
            obj.getJSONArray("topics").forEach(e1 -> {
                rootMap.get(key).getJSONArray("topics").put(e1);
            });
        } else {
            rootMap.put(key, obj);
        }
    }
}

JSONArray rootNew = new JSONArray();
rootMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
    rootNew.put(v);
});
System.out.println(rootNew.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much @LHCHIN. It looks much better, however, is there any solution which not using Jackson and just use java sdk (JSON). Cheers.

Comment: @Far Zad I have added the `org.json` solution, please check it out!

Comment: Thanks @LHCHIN. And my last question is as  Andreas said it's impossible to use streams to rewrite this piece of code. Am I right?

Comment: @Far Zad I totally agreed what @Andreas said. It's possible to rewrite this code snippet by using `Stream`, but I think it is not suitable for this case and code may be much more complicated.

Comment: @Far Zad You're welcome. And please accept my post as answer if it did solved your problem, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @LHCHIN. What I was looking for is some stream solution to make it simpler, which you and Andreas said it's not possible (at least yet). That's why I thought it would be better to keep this question unanswered until the right solution arrives (maybe in new versions of Java). But, you were helpful, and that's why I rated your answer.

Comment: @Far Zad I see, but I didn't say it is impossible to use `Stream` solution, it depends. Not everything is better to use `Stream`, the question is why you want to use it? So that's why I agreed with what @Andreas said, you should use the RIGHT tool to do the RIGHT thing!

Comment: I agree with you. Maybe I couldn't ask my question clear. Since I'm trying the new feature in Java, I decided to convert my existing code to the newest technologies in Java. Thus, I thought one solution would be Streams and Lambda for the loops and conditions. But when I tried Streams and Lambda for that piece of code, I realized it would get longer and more complicated than what I'd written before. That's why I came here to ask: is there any stream (with/without Lambda) solution to make that piece of code more straightforward and shorter (which I don't know yet) or not.

Comment: And because You and Andrea told me there is no better solution (I meant "there is no better solution" when I said "impossible"), so I thought this could be a case for the future to have some new feature in Java to make this kind of code more straightforward using Streams or whatever techniques. Does that make sense?